# What is this houseplant with large waxy leaves and a reddish base?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I have a problem with my house plant that I want to research on the net about what may have caused it and how to prevent it.  The problem is I have no idea of the name of the plant.  It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [philodendron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philodendron) plant. Probably a cultivar like ["Red Congo"](http://www.ambius.com/ambius-catalogs/floor-plants/medium-light/philodendron-red-congo/index.html).  I don't see any problems with this plant in the photo.  The thing that does surprise people is the speed with which the aerial roots grow.  I did maintenance at a hotel which had a similar cultivar in good light and the manager complained about the "snakes" coming out of the pots.  It did no good to explain that they were roots....

Cultivation

- low to medium light
- avoid cold temperatures and over watering
- happy to be pot bound
- mature specimens grow aerial roots
- Edit: they are [Aroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aroideae) and have a flower structure which has a hood and a spathe inside it. It opens up, waits for a beetle to propagate it and then drops off. Their relatives, the [spathiphyllums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spathiphyllum),  have many flowers at the same time. With spaths you can get the flower to last longer if you break off the spathe at the base. This will probably work with Philodendrons too. It does no harm to any aroid for the flower to eventually die.

Comment: thanks for the info!  my problem was that a piece of it fell off with no reason.  i thought it was a new leaf forming .. but actually after reading the wikipedia link you have included, i think it is the plants .. err .. genitals!  is it normal for them to fall off?!