# Can anyone tell me what this plant is?

Tags: identification

[image]

I cannot find out what this plant is called. It blooms bright red leaves that eventually turn green.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old philodendron.  Possibly the Congo variety or 'Prince of Orange' .  There are many varieties but they all behave similarly.  Check this [link](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4865/what-is-this-houseplant-with-large-waxy-leaves-and-a-reddish-base/4866#4866)