# Please let me know what type of plant I purchased here? And how to take care of this.

Tags: identification, plant-care

Please let me know what type of plant I purchased here? And how to take care of this.
He are some pics of it... 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's a type of [philodendron Selloum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philodendron_bipinnatifidum).  See this [link](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4865/what-is-this-houseplant-with-large-waxy-leaves-and-a-reddish-base/4866#4866) for details.