# Identify this houseplant with large green split lobed leaves

Tags: identification, houseplants, office-gardening

Another tenant in our office building left this plant.  So inherited another child, which I am happy to do.  Any care advice is welcome as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this houseplant with large waxy leaves and a reddish base?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4865/what-is-this-houseplant-with-large-waxy-leaves-and-a-reddish-base)

Comment: @kevinsky assuming the Split-leaf Philodendron ID is correct, it's definitely not the same species of plant as your link.They may share a genus, but that's about it.

Comment: @Gardner J One is a cultivar of a close relative. Care advice is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be a split-leaf philodendron. They like a warm room with bright, filtered sunlight and should be watered as soon as the soil is dry. They are, in their native habitat, a climber, so you may notice aerial roots growing out of the plant near the soil. If you give it something to climb (like a post stuck into the pot), you can train it to climb. Just be careful adding the post, so you minimize damage to the roots. You'd also want to make sure that you moisten the post when you water the plant, so the aerial roots get water as well.

Answer (score 1):

Michelle is close with the family, and most of what she said still applies. But if you want to be exact, it isn't a split-leaf philodendron (Monstera deliciosa), it is a **Philodendron bipinnatifidum**. [More information can be found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philodendron_bipinnatifidum)

Comment: I've never heard of *Monstera* being referred to as Split-Leaf Philodendron. Though @michelle didn't give a full scientific name which could have avoided confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Is it not a [Japanese Aralia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatsia_japonica)? A split leaf philodendron doesn't have the same lobulated leaves.

Comment: Can you add more details about why you think it is a Japanese Aralia? Answers that lack detail could  be removed.

Comment: *Fatsia japonica* is rather different to this with only 7-9 lobes per leaf. In *Fatsia*, the central vein in each lobe join at the petiole whereas in this plant they are distributed along the midrib of the leave. The colour of this plant is a lot darker than *Fatsia*.

Comment: It sure is not a False Aralia. And freezing is bad for it.