# Please help me identify this flower

Tags: identification, flowers

[image]
[image]
[image]

It just started growing in my garden and I don't know what it is.

Comment: Looks like Audrey II to me.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a **Philodendron Bipinnatifidum.** However, to be sure, it might be helpful to know your location, more about the area it is growing, and have a picture of the top of the leaves.

It appears similar to this plant: 
[Identify this houseplant with large green split lobed leaves](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/20713/identify-this-houseplant-with-large-green-split-lobed-leaves/31484#31484)

*I would have just commented, but do not have enough reputation to comment yet*

Answer (score 2):

I think this is one of the Arisaema lilies and not Philodendron (which has white flowers, not red) - but need to see the upper side of all the leaves present to be sure. It looks as if the flower is going to be typical of Arisaema, though it's not opened yet, but they do have this speckled or blotched look to the flowering stems. Some have palmate leaves like these, other varieties don't, so I'm not sure which variety it actually is, but it would be useful to see the leaves from the top view. Once the flower has opened up, that would also help with an accurate ID.